# jquery mobile 1.4.2 a class='ui-btn' cant change theme

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the theme of the following button:

```
<a href='#PopUpAddNumber' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' class='ui-btn' >New</a>
```

to be `data-theme='c'` however this doesn't have any effect, neither does `class='ui-btn-c'`

I had a look at this upgrade guide http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/ and although it mentions this in the buttons section it doesn't actually show how to change the theme.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: should be `ui-btn` and `ui-btn-c`.

Comment: 1.4 comes with only A and B themes unless you create a custome theme with extra swatches. Have you created a theme with a C swatch and included it in your project properly?